# Get Mutual_Likes from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get the mutual likes using the facebook graph API. But I'm having difficulties, I'm testing using the Explorer Application (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Using the following request:
`ID?fields=context{mutual_likes}`

But if I use **my** application it returns only the count as

> "total_count": 0

But I know there are mutual likes. In fact, if I use the Graph API Explorer Application, (changing the ID) it works and brings the mutual likes.

Both users I'm testing with are friends in facebook and have their likes public. My app has recently been approved to use the *user_likes* permission. And maybe I'm missing something, I was hoping you could help me achieve this.

Comment: _“My app has recently been approved to use the user_likes permission”_ – and did both users _grant_ that permission to your app?

Comment: Yes, both have. In fact I've tested this permission before by getting each user likes separately, with no problem. The problem is when I try to get the **mutual** likes.

Comment: So you are using the access token of your current app user A for the request, and the id is that of their friend B, right?

Comment: And another thing, the users themselves are friends here, right? Because if they are not, you need to make the request server-side, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/41843557/1427878

Comment: Still having this problem. Yes, the users I'm testing with are friends in Facebook and have their likes public, although I hope this is not a requirement for mutual LIKES, since the idea of the app is to **meet**  new people who you have stuff in common with. 

I haven't try to make the request server side, because I don't know how to do it, but according to the documentation [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user.context/mutual_likes) I should be able to do it with javascript, with the permissions I currently have. How can I contact FB support for help?

Comment: Try the request in Graph API Explorer, I think that sends an app-secret proof automatically. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , But as I mention in the initial question I am already using the Graph API Explorer and doesn't work. I've also tried calling my app through the web usinig Javascritp, and I get the same result. What I haven't tried is making the request using server-side language like PHP like you suggested before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why the request returned only the count as 0. It had nothing to do with making the request server-side.

I managed to get the **mutual_likes** by having the users also approve the **user_friends** permission. *Even though I wasn't going to use it in the GET request.*

Apparently you need both permissions (user_likes & user_friends) if you plan to extract anything from the context fields of a user.

Hope it helps someone else.