# Facebook all_mutual_friends not working

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an iOS app that connects to Facebook's all_mutual_friends API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/all_mutual_friends/

The app has been reviewed and approved to connect to this API.

When I make the graph call per the documentation:

```
        let params = ["fields":"context.fields(all_mutual_friends.fields(picture.width(500).height(200)))"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(facebookID)", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "GET").startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
        print("result: \(result)")
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
```

I get the following result:

```
result: {
    context =     {
        id = dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQ8qbGU5YUiZAKn8g4zuCb1LCMGj3PiCXfe7B72X5DoKkbMpHZA395xRT0iV8D84NQIZBCjJ3VRKC9uNUrMZCiwIeZBOSTRndZCQKi4pgiIgLoxI3xAZD;
    };
    id = 10208913134493418;
}
```

The above response is when we have a mutual friend who has the app installed.

Does anyone know how to get the list of mutual friends?

---

If I am Facebook friends with the person, I successfully receive a list of mutual friends making the same graph call. This is the response:

```
  context =     {
    "all_mutual_friends" =         {
        data =             (
                            {
                "first_name" = Mary;
                picture =                     {
                    data =                         {
                        height = 200;
                        "is_silhouette" = 0;
                        url = "https://...";
                        width = 200;
                    };
                };
            }, //... 24 more results
```

This is great because there is data, but it is limited to 25 mutual friends. Is there a way to increase the limit above 25?

Comment: To get all mutual friends you need to do the request from the server. And include app proof. And if you want to see more you need to use pagination

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook documentation you referred above :

> The All Mutual Friends API must be called from your server to obtain the full list of mutual friends. Calling this API in JavaScript, Android, or iOS client code will omit some of the results.

This explains the limit you are facing. :)